# Which galaxy was featured in Guardians of the Galaxy?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

The movie *Guardians of the Galaxy* takes place in space, presumably far from Earth. However, it's close enough that the Ravagers can go there to pick up Peter, and most people assume the Guardians themselves will end up on Earth in time for *Infinity Wars*.

In the source comics, the places featured in the movie are spread out: Xandar is the in Andromeda galaxy, while Hala (the Kree home world) is in the Large Magellanic Cloud. In the *Guardians of the Galaxy* movie (or anywhere else), do we get any information on where these places are in the MCU?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Based on the article below, James Gunn admitted that the movie Guardians of the Galaxy is set in the Andromeda Galaxy

> On Wednesday, director James Gunn tweeted in response to fan questions regarding the locations in Guardians of the Galaxy and the forthcoming Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2. At first, some misunderstood him, concluding that the Guardians were “unconnected” to the rest of the MCU, and Gunn chimed in again. **He confirmed that the Guardians occupy the Andromeda Galaxy, while the rest of the MCU is definitively within the Milky Way.**
>
> <sub><sup>**https://www.inverse.com/article/24861-james-gunn-marvel-mcu-guardians-galaxy-andromeda-avengers**</sup></sub>

Here is the link to the tweet

> Yes, another galaxy. Andromeda, to be specific.
>
> <sub><sup>**https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/806401095312478208**</sup></sub>

Comment: all right, so who's guarding *our* galaxy?

Comment: @Michael: the Avengers!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite No, they're just *Earth's* mightiest heroes.

Comment: Dr Strange is responsible for our entire dimension.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: and which galaxy is earth in? Might that be *our* galaxy? *Checkmate!!*

Comment: @Michael perhaps Flash Gordon, Phantom, and Mandrake?

Comment: @Nacht _x_, _y_, or _z_?

Comment: That makes no sense. It would take millions of years to reach the andromeda galaxy at relativistic speed. No human could ever visit there.

Comment: @Gallifreyan well, it's not [Dimension Z](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Dimension_Z_(Living_Eraser))

Comment: @user973810: The Marvel Cinematic Universe is not exactly hard sci-fi.

Comment: @user973810 in a fictional universe where instant teleportation exists I am dumbfounded you would make that claim.

Comment: @Michael - the guardian of OUR galaxy is Green Lantern. Oh, wait...

Answer (score 20):

Director James Gunn has stated several times, and directly on Twitter, that the events in the *Guardians* movies take place in the Andromeda galaxy.

Here's [Gunn responding](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/716308268398878720) to the question asked in a April 2016 tweet:

> **@CryHavoc01**: @JamesGunn @MAldinnur so The Galaxy they're Guarding isn't the Milky Way? Is it a specific Galaxy?
>
> **@JamesGunn**: Andromeda.

He gave a [similar answer](https://twitter.com/JamesGunn/status/806401095312478208) to another fan in December 2016:

> **@JamesGunn**: Yes, another galaxy. Andromeda, to be specific.