# Is Thanos a galactic, universal, or multi-universal threat?

Tags: marvel, thanos

Thanos is big in terms of the way he is feared. I want to know if he is part of only the galaxy. For example, the heroes known as "The Guardians of the Galaxy" are so named because they protect only the galaxy. Think of it like this: Where does Thanos lie on the list of big villains?

Earth: The mob. I mean Hydra.

Solar System: Hydra still

The galaxy: If not Thanos then maybe Ronan

The universe: If not Thanos then maybe Celestials

The multiverse: Galactus???

Comment: On multiple occasions he's tried (with varying degrees of success) to destroy the entire universe; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel:_The_End

Comment: “the heroes known as "The Guardians of the Galaxy" are so named because they protect only the galaxy” — are they? *[citation needed]*

Comment: Also I think [Galactus mostly just eats planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactus).

Comment: Gunn [has said](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/153012) the GotG were in the Andromeda Galaxy. I don't think this has been stated in-story, but it would suggest a universal scale to Thanos' threat, not merely galactic.

Comment: There seems to be a bucket of confusion in the answers and comments whether this question is Comics, Movies or Both.  And nowhere in the question are the Infinity Stones mentioned.  Thanos was a universal threat in the comics before the term "Infinity Stones" had ever been conceived.

Comment: Considering the second "What If...?" episode, this question should probably be narrowed to focus on either comics / MCU

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanos’s aim (in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, at least) is to kill half of the living beings (at least, the roughly-humanoid-looking ones) in the universe. As a time-saver, he’s trying to collect all six Infinity Stones, because with them he can do it with a click of his fingers. (Instead of going from planet to planet executing half the population manually, which gets surprisingly burdensome after a while.)

He hasn’t mentioned a multiverse, and neither has anyone else in the MCU. ([Except maybe the Ancient One, it turns out?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186869/is-thanos-a-galactic-universal-or-multi-universal-threat/186877#comment509024_186877)) So I guess he’s a universe-level threat? But *only half of it*. He’s quite specific about that.

Comment: It bears mentioning that, by design, he mostly doesn't care about which half

Comment: @geewhiz: sure he does! Specifically, the MCU Phase 3 half!

Comment: The Ancient One mentions the 'multiverse' a handful of times when she first sends Dr. Strange on his tea trip. She says there are an 'infinite number' of universes, with the scene implying the Dark Dimension, Quantum Realm, etc., are these other universes.

Comment: @MarkEdward: aha! I’ve only seen *Doctor Strange* once, I didn’t recall the multiverse mentions there. Interesting choice for the writers to use that term.

Comment: Well, i suppose you could call him a whole universe half-threat.

Comment: @MishaR: or a half-universe triple threat! Which I guess is a threat and a half? Although there are six stones. And one gauntlet. Whichever way you look at it, the maths is difficult.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Argh yeah I hate solving problems. Sometimes I wish I could just snap my fingers and *ohhhhh.*

Answer (score 1):

Browsing through other related threads I came across [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/63233/19592) which clearly shows The Watcher thanking Squirrel Girl

> Who had just defeated Thanos

for saving the entire **MultiVerse**

I'm no expert of the comics but taken at value this implies he's a Multiverse level threat to me!

Answer (score -1):

Universal. His only goal in the MCU is to use the infinity stones to wipe out half the population.

Infinity stones only work on their respective universes. one set of infinity stones cannot affect another universe under the domain of another set of infinity stones.

Comment: “one set of infinity stones cannot affect another universe under the domain of another set of infinity stones” — which MCU movie said that exactly?

Comment: Stones are rooted in the rules of the universe they exist in, other universes have different rules. The explanation is not in a movie, it's Marvel world building in the literature.

Comment: @PatrickHughes "the literature" couldja be more specific there?