# Why did Loki say Thor can't see Jane if he destroys the Bifrost when space travel was a thing?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

In *Thor*, we see Loki saying to Thor that if he destroys the bridge then he won't be able to see Jane again. It is further confirmed in *The Avengers* that Odin had to use dark magic to send Thor to Earth.

But in *Thor: Ragnarok*, we see Thor planning to visit Earth with all the residents of Asgard, and they plan to do that by ship. Then, in previous movies, why couldn't Thor just have taken a spaceship to visit Earth?

I calculated the time it would take to reach Earth and it's barely a day, as shown in *Avengers: Infinity War* (as in, the same day Thor's ship destroyed by Thanos, then Guardians reached that location, Guardians came to Titan following that, and Tony and Strange also reached Titan the same day).

So, what was that fuss about the Bifrost and dark magic in Avengers?

Comment: "I calculated the time it would take to reach earth" — Who says Thor's refugee ship can travel as fast as Thanos's big space donut? who says Asgard usually has access to space ships? Why would it bother, when it has the Bifrost?

Comment: Oddly there is no indication that Asgardians use / have spacecraft. Obviously they know how but don't.

Comment: I simply think that they've stayed away from the Space craft technology, obviously because they had Bifrost and ... To say it out loud, they are god's and would rather not be sharing the same technology as other mortal beings. Although not to say they won't know about any spaceship technology.

Comment: how can you tell that Loki is lying? His mouth is moving...

Comment: It seems unlikely. I mean a civilization that's some 10000+ years old or even more they wouldn't invent space travel. Fights with dark elfs was common for them. They hoarded so many things but not a single space craft? Skurge brought so many things from earth when he visited. Upon having bifrost destroyed the first thing they thought was to summon dark magic instead of buliding space craft? And it's not even that they don't have technology to invent flight. In Thor:The Dark World we specifically saw many flights in Asgard army. All these things don't make clear sense.

Comment: @samarendrachandanbinduDash “ Upon having bifrost destroyed the first thing they thought was to summon dark magic instead of buliding space craft?” — no, the first thing they thought of was repairing the Bifrost, which they managed to do within about 2 years, because they didn’t waste any time mucking about with spaceships. (If your car breaks down, do you get your woodworking tools out, start building a cart, and see if you can find a horse for sale?)

Comment: @samarendrachandanbinduDash “ In Thor:The Dark World we specifically saw many flights in Asgard army” — some scientists are now saying that flying on a world with atmosphere and gravity, and travelling through intergalactic space, are actually different.

Comment: Probably we can continue our discussion in the second comment thread. I have answered your question there.

Comment: Important clarification: are you asking WHY Loki said something? Or are you asking if you assume what Loki said is true, why would space travel not be how Thor could get to Earth from Asgard?

Comment: @NKCampbell Why would Loki lie about something that Thor knows is a lie?

Answer (score 13):

The Asgardians seem to rely quite heavily on the Bifrost to travel across the Nine Realms. As far as I can remember the only person we see travel freely in and out of Asgard not using the Bifrost is Loki. And even then, as hinted at in *Thor: The Dark World*, Loki uses some backdoor portal to travel between the realms as shown when [they escape Asgard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqHxCdi4VhU).

There is no indication that the Asgardians even have spaceships or any vehicles capable of traversing space. Even the opening scene to *Thor: The Dark World* with Bor against the Dark Elves they use the Bifrost.

That means that whilst space travel is a thing, and clearly the Asgardians are aware of it, they are not capable of it themselves outside of the Bifrost. This of course puts aside the theory where Loki is lying which whilst a possibility doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: But think about it. When bifrost was destroyed the first thing Odin did was to summon dark magic to send Thor to earth instead of trying to build a space craft ? I mean from ending of Thor and start of The Avengers nearly I guess 1 month+ duration is passed (not sure though). They should have have enough time to build one or atleast try to build one. They are sufficiently advanced as a civilization and this should have been much easier then summoning dark magic especially when it seems like a taboo in Asgard from how Loki mentioned it in The Avengers.

Comment: @samarendrachandanbinduDash maybe, maybe not. Depends where their expertise lies. Check out the tie in comic _Thor: The Dark World Prelude_ for Odin sending Thor to Earth with the dark energy.

Comment: In addition, in The Avengers (2012) Loki says to Thor upon his arrival "With the Bifrost gone, how much dark magic did father have to conjure to bring you here?" or something to that effect... indicating it is now more difficult somehow to send someone from realm to realm.

Comment: @TylerH Aye, transporting across realms with dark magic is itself very strenuous so wouldn't be done willy nilly. They expand on it a bit in _Thor: The Dark World Prelude_.

Answer (score 10):

I have some hypothesis, but they are all speculative.

There are multiple ways to travel interplanetary distances in the MCU. Bifrost is by far one of the fastest, allowing someone to go from one world to another in a moment. It may be that due to having access to this technology, Asgard never bothered to have a fleet of interplanetary ships, as Paul D. Waite suggested in comments:

> who says Asgard usually has access to space ships? Why would it bother, when it has the Bifrost?

Then, even with spaceships, long distance travel is not simple. Consider this scene from Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2:

In this scene, Rocket and Yondu are in a ship and they need to cross a large distance. They use a technology called [Universal Neural Teleportation Network](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Universal_Neural_Teleportation_Network), which uses wormholes.

> **Yondu:** It ain't healthy for a mammalian body to hop more than 50 jumps at a time.
> **Rocket:** I know that!
> **Yondu:** We're about to do 700!

It may be that Asgard is so far from Midgard (Earth) that more than 50 jumps would be required. So they would have to take too long to be practical to reach Earth - maybe more than Jane's natural lifespan.

Notice that neither the Guardians of the Galaxy nor Thor get to Earth through ships in Infinity War. Thor, Groot and Rocky arrive on Earth through Bifrost.

Comment: No actually! As I mentioned in my question it seems that Asgard and Earth are hardly 1 to 2 days away through space travel. Because all the characters in different locations meet in the same day at some planet in infinity war.

Comment: @samarendrachandanbinduDash: "all the characters in different locations meet in the same day at some planet in infinity war" — the planet you're presumably referring to is Titan, Thanos's homeworld. Tony, Stephen and Peter arrive there from earth in Ebony Maw's ship (the big round one), which for all we know has access to faster travel than other ships. The Guardians of the Galaxy arrive there from whatever galaxy they were already in, which is [probably not the same galaxy that earth's in](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153003/which-galaxy-was-featured-in-guardians-of-the-galaxy).

Comment: If that's the case then you are assuming that the ship Thor was travelling in would have taken a lifetime to reach earth which clearly doesn't make sense. And the guardians discovered the debris of asgard's destroyed ship the location they are in must be reachable from asgard in one or 2 days.

Comment: @samarendrachandanbinduDash the ship you refer to is from Sakkar or somewhere else, not from Asgard - it might be able to reach Earth within a few days for all we know. Doesn't mean that asgardian ships would have the same capacity.

Comment: @samarendrachandanbinduDash “ you are assuming that the ship Thor was travelling in would have taken a lifetime” — no, I’m not. I never said “a lifetime”. Just long enough that even if the heir to the throne of Asgard had access to such a ship (and I maintain that we see no evidence of Asgardians having any interest in developing space ships), it wouldn’t be practical to go see his girlfriend on earth *and* keep the rest of Nine Realms protected.

Comment: @samarendrachandanbinduDash “ the guardians discovered the debris of asgard's destroyed ship the location they are in must be reachable from asgard in one or 2 days” — sure. But there’s no reason to think the Guardians were anywhere near earth.

Comment: The destruction of Bifrost should have given them enough interest to build one.

Comment: @samarendrachandanbinduDash when they figured out they could get the Bifrost back up and running in two years, why spend time and effort building something much less useful?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite again creates contradiction isn't it? If they can easily get the Bifrost back up and running in two years, then why Loki would say that if Thor destroys BiFrost then he can't visit Jane again?

Comment: @samarendrachandanbinduDash: rule number one: Loki lies. Rule number two: there's no reason to think Loki or Thor know whether the Bifrost would be repairable or not. (I know that's weirdly specific for rule number two, but I don't make the rules, I just type them up.) Chances are no-one's tried destroying the Bifrost with Mjolnir before, and they were being groomed to rule Asgard, not learn the intricacies of Bifrost engineering.

Comment: (The real lesson is: don't watch Thor 2 again. They made 21 better movies specifically so you wouldn't have to.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite ok let's assume that Thor didn't know Bifrost could be rebuilt. Then after the fight ends we have a scene where he talks with Heimdall that "so earth is lost to us". To which Heimdall replies there is always hope. Why the f*** he doesn't just say we are planning to rebuild the bifrost ?

Comment: And Thor saying that earth is lost to us is completely wrong.I can accept that Thor didn't know about that BiFrost can be repaired.But Thor had read history of Asgard's fight with dark elves.And Dark elves had means of space travel. The first question would be why don't we try to do something like that.And again,as it's shown in the movies that Thor knows about Asgard history thus also knows about space travel, the decision he took at the end of the movie to destroy Bifrost is just became more cheap.Ofcourse he would destroy Bifrost because he knows that it's not the only way to earth.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116476/discussion-between-samarendra-chandan-bindu-dash-and-paul-d-waite).

Answer (score -1):

Not knowing how deep into the entire space travel part of the MCU that these films would venture, I'm thinking it was merely a slip by Marvel producers to not have Thor get back to Jane by simply jumping on a space ship and traveling through the ready available portals that everyone in the galaxy seems to have access to. The theory of Asgard being too far from Earth doesn't work since it was proven by Thanos's thugs in Infinity War not to take long at all. They literally arrived only several hours after the Hulk got there on the bifrost.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What about the theory proposed by the other answers that, since the Asgardians had Bifrost they never developed space travel, so there was no ship that could take Thor to Earth?